# How to insert background video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a `video.mp4` (640x360) and `image.jpg` (1280x720).
I want to make `image.jpg` as a background of `video.mp4` using ffmpeg:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop input image and use [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay). Example command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" -c:a copy output.mp4
```